# Values not loading inside .ascx when called from another .ascx

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm openning a modal dialog using this function:

```
   public void viewData(long labID)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "open", "$('#modProductEntry').modal('show');", true);
        btnAddSamples.Visible = false;
        btnSave.Visible = false;

        btnSave.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-warning";
        lbIcon.CssClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil";

        ViewState["RequrementsData"] = null;
        ViewState["SamplesData"] = null;

        ViewOnly = true;
        setEditValues(labID);
        laboratoryActions.disableAllFields(this);
    }
```

When calling it inside a repeater it works fine, but when I try to open it from another .ascx controller none of the values get loaded, what am I doing wrong?

Here are the 2 button click:

```
protected void btnView_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    long labID = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);
    addEditProduct.viewData(labID);
}

protected void btnViewRequest_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   addEditProduct.viewData(labReqID);
}
```

Both of them go through debugging the same exact way, but the first one work, the 2nd doesn't. The labID in both cases is '126', the modal dialog opens, but nothing get's loaded.